# How to create ref in class based component and pass it to the functional component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have this class based component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './OptionsMenu.sass'

import DropdownBox from '../DropdownBox/DropdownBox'
import Icon from '../Icon/Icon'

class OptionsMenu extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.dropdownBoxRef = React.createRef()
    }

  handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (this.dropdownBoxRef && !this.dropdownBoxRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      this.props.close()
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside)
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.props.options.map(option => (
      <li className='OptionsList-Element'>
        <div className='OptionsList-ElementIcon'>
          <Icon name={option.icon} />
        </div>
        <span>{option.label}</span>
      </li>
    ))
    return (
      <DropdownBox reference={this.dropdownBoxRef} styles={this.props.styles}>
        <ul className='OptionsList'>{options}</ul>
      </DropdownBox>
    )
  }
}

export default OptionsMenu
```

In constructor i'm creating ref, and then i want to pass it to DropdownBox component, that is rendered. In DropdownBox component i tried to use react hooks, but i think that i'ts wrong way. How to make it correctly?
Note, i dont want to switch my functional component to classbased!

Here is the code of DropdownBox component:

```
const dropdownBox = props => {
  const dropdownBoxRef = useRef(props.reference) 

  return (
    <div ref={dropdownBoxRef} className='DropdownBox-Container' style={props.styles}>
      <div className='DropdownBox'>
        <div className='DropdownBox-Triangle' />
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to get a ref to the underlying element outside the child component. For example:

```
const DropdownBox = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} className='DropdownBox-Container' style={props.styles}>
      <div className='DropdownBox'>
        <div className='DropdownBox-Triangle' />
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
));
```

Then in `OptionsMenu`:

```
 return (
      <DropdownBox ref={this.dropdownBoxRef} styles={this.props.styles}>
        <ul className='OptionsList'>{options}</ul>
      </DropdownBox>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the `reference` prop in your `DropdownBox` component to the `ref` prop of the `div` you want the reference of.

```
const dropdownBox = props => {
  return (
    <div ref={props.reference} className='DropdownBox-Container' style={props.styles}>
      { /* ... */ }
    </div>
  )
}
```

React will assign the component to the `dropdownRef` variable on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a the dropdownBox a function that will set the ref. To do this you can add in your menu component a function like the following:

```
const onDropdownRef = (ref) => {
    this.dropdownBoxRef.current = ref;
}
```

Then you give this function to your dropdown component like so: `<DropdownBox onRef={this.onDropdownRef} styles={this.props.styles}>`

Then finally in your dropdown component you give this function to the div like so:
`<div ref={props.onRef} className='DropdownBox-Container' style={props.styles}>`

This will make sure your menu will have a ref to the top div from the dropdownbox.